# Using 'this' in object method in node module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, express

Here is my module:

```
module.exports = {

    name: '',
    email: '',
    id: '',
    provider: '',
    logged_in: false,

    isLoggedIn: function(req, res, next){
        console.log(this);

    }   
};
```

I import it like so:

```
var user = require('user');
```

When I use the `isLoggedIn` function as middle with Express, the console logs the global Node object. How do I get it to log the object the function is within?

**EDIT**

So I have my user object as defined above. Depending on various factors this object is populated elsewhere in the program. I with to create a middleware function for express to quickly test of the user is logged in. The obvious place to put this function seemed to be in the user object, but I need access to the logged_in property to evaluate it properly. Hence use of this.logged_in.

Comment: I'm not sure you are getting things quite right. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct for the question asked, you should look into exporting an Object Constructor with an attached prototype chain instead of using an Object Literal if use of the `bind()` method seems dirty to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass that as a middle function, I believe you are doing something like ths

```
func(.., user.isLoggedIn, ..)
```

When you are doing like this, you are actually detaching `isLoggedIn` from the `user` object. So, by default, if not in strict mode, `this` will refer to global object. To fix this, you should [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function, like this

```
func(.., user.isLoggedIn.bind(user), ..)
```

Comment: This worked, though I suspect I've not got the best solution if I need to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You should put that with IIFE:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      id: '',
      provider: '',
      logged_in: false,

      isLoggedIn: function(req, res, next){
        console.log(this);
      }   
   }
})();
```

You could read about here:
http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iifes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions

Comment: @jibsales it's returning an object literal, so 'this' will bind to that object and not to global

Comment: I personally know what it is doing, but pointing the OP to a blog and pasting code is not very useful without an explanation